# Owl carousel "to.owl.carousel" not working in react js

Tags: reactjs, owl-carousel

i want to move carousel to the clicked item,

`$(document).on("click", ".owl-item", function () { $(".owl-carousel").trigger("to.owl.carousel", [$(this).index(), 300]); });`

but in html it's worked

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use npm package in React

[react-owl-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel)

I found a Example - [React owl carousel](https://codesandbox.io/s/ezw97?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: i used and have installed jquery @Devendra Kushwaha

Comment: You don't need jquery for that with NPM package

Comment: I have added a example in my answer you can check that as well

Comment: thanks @Devendra Kushwaha but owl carousel works, but event "to.owl.carousel" not working